# Rename directory in another date format in terminal

Tags: terminal, directory, rename

I have a problem with convert date format in directory names. Is there a way to rename the directories using from

> 11. January 2006
> 12. March 2019

to

> 2016-01-11
>
> 2019-03-07

Comment: Is the date within the directory name? Are we talking about linux? Can you show a full example of what you want to start with and what it should be in the end?

Comment: We talk about my Mac. Here I have folders called "7. January 2019" and I want to rename them in "2019-01-07".